# List of Unicode alphabetic characters

Tags: unicode, alphabetic, character-properties

I need the list of ranges of Unicode characters with the property `Alphabetic` as defined in http://www.unicode.org/Public/5.1.0/ucd/UCD.html#Alphabetic. However, I cannot find them in the Unicode Character Database no matter how I search for them. Can somebody provide a list of them or just a search facility for characters with specified Unicode properties?

Comment: If you look at my answer, I have per your request provided you with a search facility for characters with specified Unicode properties by way of [my unichars script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars).  Enjoy!

Answer (score 14):

The Unicode Character Database comprises all the text files in the distribution. It is not just a single file as it once was long ago.

The Alphabetic property is a derived property.

You really do not want to use code point ranges for this.  You want to use the property *properly*.  That’s because there are just too many of them.  Using the [*unichars* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars), we learn that there are more than ten thousand just in the Basic Multilingual Plane alone **not** counting Han or Hangul:

```
$ unichars '\p{Alphabetic}' | wc -l
   10052
```

If we include the other 16 astral planes, now we’re at fourteen thousand:

```
$ unichars -a '\p{Alphabetic}' | wc -l
   14736
```

And if we include Han and Hangul, which in fact the Alphabetic property does, we just blew the roof off of a hundred thousands code points:

```
$ unichars -ua '\p{Alphabetic}' | wc -l
  101539
```

I hope you can see that you do **not** want to specifically enumerate these using code point ranges. Down that road lies madness.

By the way, if you find the [*unichars* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars) useful, 
you might also like the [*uniprops* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops) and perhaps the [*uninames* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames).

Comment: I really like your scripts! They will be very useful for resolving a [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246651/generate-uri-friendly-unicode-code-points-from-integer-counter) I had. Thanks so much for making them. Question: when I just ran the last command above (`unichars -ua '\p{Alphabetic}' | wc -l`), I got 94332 lines instead of 101539. Any reason why that might be?

Comment: @Abe: Prolly cause you are not running Unicode 6.0.0 yet. What version of Perl are you running?  `corelist -a Unicode` will show you the pairings of Perl versions with Unicode versions.  BTW, I now have         in my [Unicode toolchest](http://training.perl.com/scripts/), with more on the way.

Comment: Ah yes, I am running Perl 5 still. I'll definitely upgrade Perl and check out your new tools. Thanks!

Comment: @Able Perl v5.8.8 had Unicode v4.1; Perl v5.8.9 and Perl v5.10.1 had Unicode v5.1; Perl v5.12 had Unicode v5.2; and Perl v5.14 has Unicode v6.0.0.  I would install Perl v5.14 if you can, and v5.12 if you cannot. Just make sure to do the CPAN `autobundle` trick to upgrade all your post-facto installed CPAN modules.

Comment: Link no longer works and is not archived by Interent Archive. Searching turns up https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Unicode-Tussle/script/unichars and https://github.com/turian/common-scripts/blob/master/unichars

Answer (score 3):

Derived Core Properties can be calculated from the other properties.

The Alphabetic property is defined as: Generated from: Lu + Ll + Lt + Lm + Lo + Nl + Other_Alphabetic

So, if you take all the characters in Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, Nl, and all the characters with the Other_Alphabetic property, you will have the Alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 2):

Citation from your source: `Generated from: Lu + Ll + Lt + Lm + Lo + Nl + Other_Alphabetic`

These Abbrevations seem to be explained [here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/5.1.0/ucd/UCD.html#General_Category_Values).

Answer (score 1):

I found the [UniView](http://rishida.net/scripts/uniview) web application which provides a nice search interface. Searching for the Letter property (with Local unchecked) gives 14723 results...

Comment: The Letter property is not the same as the Alphabetic property!!!! In Unicode 6.0.0, there are 101539 code points with the Alphabetic property but only 100520 with the Letter property, a difference of over a thousand characters. BTW, your 14k answer is off by an order of magnitude.

Comment: You're right. BTW, I think the UniView tool doesn't take Han and Hangul into account.

Comment: Link is dead :/