# Java - \pL [\x00-\x7F]+ regex fails to get non English characters using String.match

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate name,saved in a String, which can be in any language with spaces using [\p{L}](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop):

> You can match a single character belonging to the "letter" category with \p{L}

I tried to use `String.matches`, but it failed to match non English characters, even for 1 character, for example

```
String name = "อั";
boolean isMatch = name.matches("[\\p{L}]+")); // return false
```

I tried with/without brackets, adding `+` for multiple letters, but it's always failing to match non English characters

Is there an issue using `String.matches` with `\p{L}`?

I failed also using `[\\x00-\\x7F]+` suggested in [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> ```
> \p{ASCII} All ASCII:[\x00-\x7F]
> ```

Comment: your name has only ONE single character?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger no, but even when using \pL on a one character match, it still fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bear in mind that Java regex parses strings as collections of Unicode code units, not code points. `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter from the BMP plane, it does not match letters glued with diacritics after them.

Since your input can contain letters and diacritics you should at least use both `\p{L}` and `\p{M}` Unicode property classes in your character class:

```
String regex = "[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+";
```

If the input string can contain words separated with whitespaces, you may add `\s` shorthand class and to match any kind of whitespace you may compile this regex with `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag:

```
String regex = "(?U)[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\s]+";
```

Note that this regex allows entering diacritics, letters and whitespaces in any order. If you need a more precise regex (e.g. diacritics only allowed after a base letter) you may consider something like

```
String regex = "(?U)\\s*(?>\\p{L}\\p{M}*+)+(?:\\s+(?>\\p{L}\\p{M}*+)+)*\\s*";
```

Here, `(?>\\p{L}\\p{M}*+)+` matches one or more letters each followed with zero or more diacritics, `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces and `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespaces.

**`\p{IsAlphabetic}` vs. `[\p{L}\p{M}]`**

If you check the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l5693), `\p{Alphabetic}` checks if `Character.isAlphabetic(ch)` is true. It is true if the char belongs to any of the following classes: `UPPERCASE_LETTER`, `LOWERCASE_LETTER`, `TITLECASE_LETTER`, `MODIFIER_LETTER`, `OTHER_LETTER`, `LETTER_NUMBER` **or it has contributory property Other_Alphabetic**. It [is derived from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843347) `Lu + Ll + Lt + Lm + Lo + Nl + Other_Alphabetic`.

While all those `L` subclasses form the general `L` class, note that `Other_Alphabetic` also includes  [*Letter number* `Nl`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Nl) class, and it includes more chars than `\p{M}` class, see [this reference](https://www.sql-und-xml.de/unicode-database/other_alphabetic.html) (although it is in German, the categories and char names are in English).

So, **`\p{IsAlphabetic}` is broader than `[\p{L}\p{M}]`** and you should make the right decision based on the languages you want to support.

Comment: Thank you,why is it better then `\p{IsAlphabetic}`?

Comment: @user7294900 I added some more details.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found is using [\p{IsAlphabetic}](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> \p{Alpha}  An alphabetic character:\p{IsAlphabetic}

```
boolean isMatch = name.matches("[ \\p{IsAlphabetic}]+"))
```

Which doesn't work in sites as https://regex101.com/ in [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JsDc3o/1)

Answer (score 1):

Googled that character to find the language. Seems to be Thai. Thai Unicode character range is: [0E00 to 0E7F](https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0E00-0E7F):

When you are working with unicode characters you can use `\u`. So, the regex should be look like this:

```
[\u0E00-\u0E7F]
```

Which is match in this [REGEX test](https://regex101.com/r/PXrNY2/1) with your character.

If you want to match any languages use this:

```
[\p{L}]
```

Which is match in this [REGEX test](https://regex101.com/r/Wejr8k/1) with your example characters.

Comment: I need English and non English characters, not only Thai, but thanks for the Thai reference

Answer (score 1):

There are two characters there.  The first is a letter, the second is a non-letter mark.

```
String name = "\u0e2d";
boolean isMatch = name.matches("[\\p{L}]+"); // true
```

works, but

```
String name = "\u0e2d\u0e31";
boolean isMatch = name.matches("[\\p{L}]+"); // false
```

does not because      ั [U+E31](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e31/index.htm) is a Non-Spacing Mark [NSM], not a letter.

Comment: I'll check it, but it's also from user input and also why/how `IsAlphabetic` is working in this case?

Comment: @user7294900.  Sorry.  My mistake.  I'm seeing a diacritical now    ั [U+E31](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e31/index.htm)

Comment: The logical conclusion being that `"[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+"` will correctly match that string.

Answer (score 1):

Try including more categories:

```regex
[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}\p{Pd}\p{Po}\p{Sk}]+
```

Note that it might be best to simply not validate names. People can't really complain if they entered it wrong but your system didn't catch it. However, it's much more of a problem if someone is unable to enter their name. If you do insist on adding validation, *please* make it overridable: that should have the advantages of each method without their disadvantages.

Comment: I must validate user input, can you explain the categories? Can you add reference link/demo?

Comment: @user7294900 I used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property and https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category to look up the categories.

Comment: Thank you for responding, it works, but it's adding alot of questions, for example why adding *\p{Pd} matches any kind of hyphen or dash
\p{Po} matches any kind of punctuation character that is not a dash, bracket, quote or connector*?

Comment: @user7294900 If you're asking why the Unicode standard was designed the way it was, I don't have any answers. I also think it's a mess. If you're asking something, could you please clarify your question?