# Check if a string has no alphabets

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find whether the string has only numbers and special characters.

I tried below code but it isn't working

```
String text="123$%$443";
String regex = "[0-9]+";
String splChrs = "-/@#$%^&_+=()" ;
if ((text.matches(regex)) && (text.matches("[" + splChrs + "]+"))) {
  System.out.println("no alphabets");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "no alphabets"? if you mean "doesn't contain letters", all you need to check is whether it contains a letter somewhere

Comment: Your two regular expressions and the logical `&&` do *not* check `text` for containining  *no* letters `[a-z]`.

Comment: Only no English letters or any letters?

Answer (score 14):

Just exclude using `^` the alphabetical letters:

```
[^a-zA-Z]+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEHUga/2)

Comment: this check must be done on all the text  -->  ^[^a-zA-Z]+$

Comment: @leMandarin but method return true when matches the whole String https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check that `text` **does not contain any letter `[A-Za-z]`**, try this:

```
if (!text.matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
  System.out.println("no letters");
}
```

If you want to check that `text` **contains only numbers and the given special characters**, try this:

```
String regex = "[0-9\\-/@#$%^&_+=()]+";
if (text.matches(regex)) {
  System.out.println("no letters");
}
```

Note that the `-` must be escpade by a `\` which itself must be escaped.

Comment: double quotes " it is also a special character how can i add it?

Comment: How can i add backslash \

Comment: String regex="[0-9\\-/@~#$%!^&'*<>,-./:\"`;?{}|_+=()\\s]+"; i am using like this now i had to add backslash \ and square brackets [ ].How can i add it?and also tell me if i missed any special character.

Answer (score 2):

Here are several solutions that might work for various requirements:

**Text must have no ASCII-only letters**

```
if (text.matches("\\P{Alpha}+")) {
  System.out.println("No ASCII letters");
}
```

**Text must have no letter from the whole BMP plane**

```
if (text.matches("\\P{L}+")) {
  System.out.println("No Unicode letters");
}
```

**Text must have no [alphabetic chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843347)**

```
if (text.matches("\\P{IsAlphabetic}+")) {
  System.out.println("No alphabetic chars");
}
```

*Note: the `IsAlphabetic` class includes `L`, `Nl` (Letter number) and `Other_Alphabetic` categories and might be too broad, but is good if you need to check for letters and diacritics.

The `String#matches` method requires a full string match, hence no anchors (`^`/`\A` and `$`/`\z`) are used in the above code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

in java regex 'match' and 'find' are different methods.If your string just contains letters you wanna find,use 'find'.Or if your wanna match the whole string,use 'match'