# How does isalnum() and isalpha works in python? Returning true when chinese is included

Tags: python

Im not sure why the program return true when the string contains chinese characters.

```
    cop = "奶helloworld茶"
    print(cop)
    print(cop.isalpha())
    print(cop.isalnum())
```

This gives output like this.

```
    奶helloworld茶
    True
    True
```

Comment: Did you check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chinese characters are considered alphabetic in Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843653/5923139), so `isalpha` and `isalnum` will return `True` for them. If you don't want this, then restrict it to being ascii:

```py
print(cop.isascii() and cop.isalpha()) # False
```